# How to increase Scrapy crawling speed when there are many duplicates links

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm using Scrapy to crawl a website with millions of pages that I need to follow and extract information from it.

The crawler is currently scraping only two hundred pages per minute and I need to speed it up.

For each page the crawler extracts its links and follows them. The problem is that each page has about 600 links and most of them are on all pages and I think that is the reason why it's taking so long since the crawler is calling the Request function for all links even if they are duplicated.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
def parse_data(self, response):
    item = URL() 
    outlinks_extrated = [l.url for l in LinkExtractor(allow_domains=self.allowed_domains, deny_extensions = self.reg_deny, unique=False, restrict_xpaths=self.xpath_outlinks, tags=self.tags, deny = self.regex_denied).extract_links(response)]
    for url in outlinks_extrated: 
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_data) 
    item['url'] = response.request.url
    yield item
```

I already tried setting the concurrent requests and concurrent requests per domain but didn't work.

Does anyone know why it takes so long to crawl and how can I speed it up?

Comment: What is your CPU usage during this scraping run?  Scrapy filters duplicate urls by default using `RFPDupefilter` which is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood you correctly one of the problem you have is duplicate links. Why not simply make a set of links parsed and check all links you are going to parse against this set? Here's what I mean:

```
links_visited = set()

def parse_data(self, response):
    item = URL() 
    outlinks_extrated = [l.url for l in LinkExtractor(allow_domains=self.allowed_domains, deny_extensions = self.reg_deny, unique=False, restrict_xpaths=self.xpath_outlinks, tags=self.tags, deny = self.regex_denied).extract_links(response)]
    for url in outlinks_extrated:
        if url not in links_visited:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_data)
            links_visited.add(url)
    item['url'] = response.request.url
    yield item
```

This way you will be sure you will not re-visit URLs.

EDIT: Maybe a better solution would be to instantiate `scrapy.Request` once; this way you can make use of `dont_filter` parameter (check https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html for more info; your requests will be filtered by default so you won't visit duplicate URLs).

Comment: Thanks! Using the set the crawler can scrape twice as many pages per minute. The `dont_filter` parameter is already set to true by default so it doesn't visit duplicated URLs but I don't know why it takes more time when using Request function with all links if it is not following duplicated links.

Comment: You wrote: "The problem is that each page has about 600 links and most of them are on all pages"
But each time you instantiate a new `Request` you simply give it a URL; these instances have no info about those links you visited using previous instances of this class. And in each loop some portion of URLs is duplicated so you have to check for this. So probably best (or at least working) solution would be using sets.

Also please note that to enable filtering `dont_filter` must be `False`.